# contents of text area not posting

Tags: php, html, forms, post, textarea

I have a form located at https://pnrbuilder.com/_popups/feedback_popup.html

The form uses post to pass the input to a php page which sends an email with the contents of the post then redirects the user.

The input fields work fine but the textarea content doesnt make it to the email.

Any idea what Im doing wrong?

the PHP Page:

```
<?php
/*
This first bit sets the email address that you want the form to be submitted to.
You will need to change this value to a valid email address that you can access.
*/
$webmaster_email = "support@email.com";

/*
This bit sets the URLs of the supporting pages.
If you change the names of any of the pages, you will need to change the values here.
*/
$feedback_page = "feedback_form.html";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "thank_you.html";


/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$EmailAddress = $_POST['EmailAddress'] ;
$IssueType = $_POST['IssueType'] ;
$Comments = $_POST['Comments'] ;

/*
The following function checks for email injection.
Specifically, it checks for carriage returns - typically used by spammers to inject a CC list.
*/
function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}


// If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
if ( isInjected($EmailAddress) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If we passed the previous test, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else {
mail( "$webmaster_email, test@email.com", "Feedback",
  $EmailAddress, $IssueType, $Comments );
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>
```

If I put the below at the top of my php page it DOES echo out the contents of the textarea

```
echo $_POST["EmailAddress"];
echo $_POST["IssueType"];
echo $_POST["Comments"];
```

Comment: Could you please try outputting the `$_POST` variables, *before* sending them via e-mail? Do they not show up?

Comment: edit above: Yes the text area does show up before emailing

Comment: Please check my answer below. This should do the trick for you. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sending email**

You're passing the wrong parameters to `mail()`:

```
mail( "$webmaster_email, designedondemandcorp@gmail.com", "Feedback", $EmailAddress, $IssueType, $Comments);
```

That should be:

```
$contents = <<<EOM
Email: $emailAddress

Issue type: $IssueType

Comments:
$Comments
EOM;

mail( "$webmaster_email, designedondemandcorp@gmail.com", "Feedback", $contents);
```

**Email validation**

Secondly, you should use proper email validation:

```
$emailAddress = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'EmailAddress', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if ($emailAddress === false) {
    header( "Location: $error_page" );
}
```

Comment: Perfect the mail part works great now, thank you VERY much BTW, I tried to use the email validation but I get the below when the php page loads:  `Warning: filter_input() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given in /home/content/08/10125908/html/_popups/send_mail.php on line 51`

Comment: I changed `emailAddress` in your post to `EmailAddress` but I still get the same error

Comment: @DelightedD0D Sorry, I missed adding `INPUT_POST` as the first argument :)

Answer (score 2):

Please, check out the correct form of PHP's `mail` function :

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

**Reference :** http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

---

Message is supposed to be the 3rd parameter, nope?

What you've written is :

```
mail( "$webmaster_email, designedondemandcorp@gmail.com", "Feedback",
  $EmailAddress, $IssueType, $Comments );
```

**Rewrite it like this :**

```
$messageBody = "Comments : ".$Comments." Issue : ".$IssueType;
mail("$webmaster_email, designedondemandcorp@gmail.com", "Feedback", $messageBody);
```

Just wanted it to see if there was something wrong with the `$_POST`, but I guess my code above will fix the issue (just bundle up all your data in a `$messageBody` var and pass it on to the `mail` function).

Comment: Thank you for your help this DID work. Ultimately im gonna go with Jack's answer as it formats the email in a more readable way.

Comment: @DelightedD0D Glad to have helped, mate! ;-) (Sidenote : I just wrapped a quick way to show how it should be done...)